# Python tkinter- deleting selected listbox item

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I need to be able to highlight one or multiple items in a given listbox and remove them. I have looked at other people's questions on here but for some reason when I try to delete the items, nothing happens at all.

Below is my code that I am using. Can anyone take a look and help me please?

```
import tkinter

class Remove_Button_Widget():

    def __init__(self):
        self.Remove_Button = tkinter.Button(master, text= "Remove", height = 2, width = 6, command =lambda :remove_button().remove_functionality(Robot_Files_Found_Widgets().ROBOT_FILE_LIST))
        self.Remove_Button.place(x=362,y=350)

class Robot_Files_Found_Widgets():


    def __init__(self):
        self.Robot_Files_Ran_Frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.Robot_Files_Ran_Frame.place(bordermode=tkinter.INSIDE, height=30, width=200, y=250, x=35)

        self.Display_Robot_Files_Frame = tkinter.Frame(master, borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=1,
                                              highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
        self.Display_Robot_Files_Frame.place(bordermode=tkinter.INSIDE, height=200, width=300, y=285, x=50)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST = tkinter.Listbox(self.Display_Robot_Files_Frame,selectmode=tkinter.MULTIPLE)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.place(bordermode=tkinter.INSIDE, height=196, width=296)

        self.Scroll_Bar_x = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
        self.Scroll_Bar_x.config(command=self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.xview)
        self.Scroll_Bar_x.pack(fill=tkinter.X, side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.config(xscrollcommand=self.Scroll_Bar_x.set)
        self.Scroll_Bar_y = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
        self.Scroll_Bar_y.config(command=self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.yview)
        self.Scroll_Bar_y.pack(fill=tkinter.Y, side=tkinter.RIGHT)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.config(yscrollcommand=self.Scroll_Bar_y.set)
        list = []
        for x in range(0,15):
            list.append(x)
        for y in list:
            self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.insert(0,y)

class remove_button():

    def remove_functionality(self, ROBOT_FILE_LIST):
        sel = ROBOT_FILE_LIST.curselection()
        # iterate over sel, deleting each item
        for index in sel:
            ROBOT_FILE_LIST.delete(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":


    master = tkinter.Tk()
    master.title("Test Runner")
    master.geometry("750x500")
    master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    Robot_Files_Found_Widgets()
    Remove_Button_Widget()
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix your indention on this. Also we need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have code here that does not even point to anything and is unnecessary for testing.

Comment: I updated the code, if you will have a look please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason your button is not working is due to how you built your lambda. Because you are calling the class each time you press the button you are not actually editing the first instance of that class used to build your GUI. You would need to save a reference to the class instance in order to get this to work. Another problem I can see that you should avoid is calling your list `list`. Do not name variables the same thing as built in methods. This will break things in your code.

I do not think you should be building so many classes. All of your functionality here can be built into a single class. That said you also need `reversed()` when deleting your index selections so you are not skipping index.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Test Runner")
        self.geometry("750x500")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.robot_files_ran_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.robot_files_ran_frame.place(bordermode=tk.INSIDE, height=30, width=200, y=250, x=35)

        self.display_robot_files_frame = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=1,
                                              highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
        self.display_robot_files_frame.place(bordermode=tk.INSIDE, height=200, width=300, y=285, x=50)
        self.robot_file_list = tk.Listbox(self.display_robot_files_frame,selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
        self.robot_file_list.place(bordermode=tk.INSIDE, height=196, width=296)

        self.scroll_bar_x = tk.Scrollbar(self.robot_file_list, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.scroll_bar_x.config(command=self.robot_file_list.xview)
        self.scroll_bar_x.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)
        self.robot_file_list.config(xscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar_x.set)
        self.scroll_bar_y = tk.Scrollbar(self.robot_file_list, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.scroll_bar_y.config(command=self.robot_file_list.yview)
        self.scroll_bar_y.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.robot_file_list.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar_y.set)
        some_list = []

        for x in range(0,15):
            some_list.append(x)

        for y in some_list:
            self.robot_file_list.insert(0, y)

        self.remove_button = tk.Button(self, text= "Remove", height=2, width=6, command=self.remove_functionality)
        self.remove_button.place(x=362, y=350)

    def remove_functionality(self):
        sel = self.robot_file_list.curselection()
        # added reversed here so index deletion work for multiple selections.
        for index in reversed(sel):
            self.robot_file_list.delete(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().mainloop()
```

Just for sake of correcting the original issue without reworking the entire code you need to save a reference to your listbox and pass that to your button for a variable.

Here is an example using your code with the saved variable to be passed between classes.

```
import tkinter


class Remove_Button_Widget():
    def __init__(self, var1):
        variable_to_pass = var1
        self.Remove_Button = tkinter.Button(master, text="Remove", height=2, width=6, command=lambda :remove_button().remove_functionality(variable_to_pass))
        self.Remove_Button.place(x=362,y=350)


class Robot_Files_Found_Widgets():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Robot_Files_Ran_Frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.Robot_Files_Ran_Frame.place(bordermode = tkinter.INSIDE, height=30, width=200, y=250, x=35)
        self.Display_Robot_Files_Frame = tkinter.Frame(master, borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=1,
                                              highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
        self.Display_Robot_Files_Frame.place(bordermode = tkinter.INSIDE, height=200, width=300, y=285, x=50)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST = tkinter.Listbox(self.Display_Robot_Files_Frame,selectmode = tkinter.MULTIPLE)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.place(bordermode = tkinter.INSIDE, height=196, width=296)

        self.Scroll_Bar_x = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST, orient = tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
        self.Scroll_Bar_x.config(command=self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.xview)
        self.Scroll_Bar_x.pack(fill = tkinter.X, side = tkinter.BOTTOM)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.config(xscrollcommand=self.Scroll_Bar_x.set)
        self.Scroll_Bar_y = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST, orient = tkinter.VERTICAL)
        self.Scroll_Bar_y.config(command=self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.yview)
        self.Scroll_Bar_y.pack(fill = tkinter.Y, side = tkinter.RIGHT)
        self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.config(yscrollcommand=self.Scroll_Bar_y.set)
        some_list = []
        for x in range(0,15):
            some_list.append(x)
        for y in some_list:
            self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST.insert(0, y)
        Remove_Button_Widget(self.ROBOT_FILE_LIST)


class remove_button():
    def remove_functionality(self, ROBOT_FILE_LIST):
        sel = ROBOT_FILE_LIST.curselection()
        # iterate over sel, deleting each item
        for index in reversed(sel):
            ROBOT_FILE_LIST.delete(index)


if __name__ =="__main__":
    master = tkinter.Tk()
    master.title("Test Runner")
    master.geometry("750x500")
    master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    Robot_Files_Found_Widgets()
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: @S.McWhorter I have added a 2nd example as well to show you how your code could work while using multiple classes like your example.

Comment: Thank you for that! How would you remove that selected item from the list? I tried making `global some_list` and then adding in `del some_list[index]` in the remove_functionality function. But it deletes the the opposite end variable in the list.

Comment: well when using classes you should avoid `global`. Make `some_list` a class attribute with `self` so you can access it from anywhere. That said it depends on how you want to remove data from the list. Where in the code are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm using the first example you gave. In the `remove_functionality` function. Inside the `for index in reversed(sel)`. I am trying to delete the corresponding list item from the list. But as of now it deletes the opposite ended list item.

Comment: @S.McWhorter for the list part are you trying to delete from the list and use that to update the listbox? or  Just want to delete it from the list so the list matches what the listbox has?

Comment: So that it matches what the listbox has.

Comment: @S.McWhorter that one might be a bit more tricky. Due to the index you are inserting your numbers in the listbox at we are not going to be able to simple delete the same index we normally would. Please ask a new question about the list so we can work on that as it is very much a separate question than the listbox issue.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118941/python-tkinter-delete-listbox-item-and-corresponding-list-item

Answer (score 1):

The method `.curselection()` returns a tuple of the indices of the items selected. The method `.delete()` takes the data stated in the error at the top of your question, it will not accept a tuple.

You have the selectmode for your Listbox set as MULTIPLE, so you need to iterate over the tuple returned by `curselection()` and delete each index one by one.

```
def remove_functionality(self,ROBOT_FILE_LIST):
    sel = ROBOT_FILE_LIST.curselection()
    # iterate over sel, deleting each item
    for index in sel[::-1]:
        ROBOT_FILE_LIST.delete(index)
```

Comment: I updated the code, but when I use this it doesn't do anything. No errors, just does not do anything.

Comment: I can't replicate the error you're getting but I have noticed a bug which I'll fix which might fix it. Basically, when you delete the first item from the listbox, all the items shift up an index so the indices from .curselection are wrong.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm not sure what is wrong here. But even your updated answer it still does nothing. I highlight items in the listbox and then click the remove button but it does not remove anything.

Comment: The problem is your classes, they're a bit all over the place, have a look at Mike - SMT's answer

Comment: @S.McWhorter strava is correct on the indexing backwards portion but your main problem is how you call the class in your button.